# UCWA: error when sending multiple messages

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I'm trying to code a Skype for Business chatbot using UCWA. For now, I can successfully create an application, send a message invitation and finally send a message which is correctly received. The problem is: if I send another message, it is never received by its recipient.

In the event, the message status is "Failure", but no other helpful information are given.

I used [Matthew Proctor's tutorial](https://www.matthewproctor.com/Send-An-IM-With-UCWA-Sending-the-IM/) and official [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/sendanim). Microsoft example send only one message before closing the conversation so no indication is given about my problem. The Matthew Proctor's tutorial only says to rerun the POST request `POST https://myhostname.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e/messaging/messages`. And I correctly call the event resource between each message.

Here are the steps performed in my script:

```
sd.send_user_message_invitation()
conv_id = sd.get_conversation_ID_in_event()
sd.send_message(conv_id, "Premier message")
sd.get_event()
sd.send_message(conv_id, "Deuxième message")
sd.get_event()
sd.terminate_conversation(conv_id)
```

Here is the response I get when I make a GET request on the event URL after the first message (which is correctly received):

`GET https://myhostname.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/events?ack=2`

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {"href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/events?ack=2"},
        "next": {"href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/events?ack=3"}
    },
    "sender": [
        {
            "rel": "conversation",
            "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e",
            "events": [
                {
                    "link": {
                        "rel": "message",
                        "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e/messaging/messages/2"
                    },
                    "status": "Success",
                    "_embedded": {
                        "message": {
                            "direction": "Outgoing",
                            "timeStamp": "\/Date(1581608086884)\/",
                            "_links": {
                                "self": {"href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e/messaging/messages/2"},
                                "messaging": {"href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e/messaging"}
                            },
                            "rel": "message"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "completed"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is what I get when I make a GET request on the event URL after the second (or any following sent) message (which is not received):

`GET https://myhostname.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/events?ack=3`

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {"href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/events?ack=3"},
        "next": {"href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/events?ack=4"}
    },
    "sender": [
        {
            "rel": "conversation",
            "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e",
            "events": [
                {
                    "link": {
                        "rel": "message",
                        "href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e/messaging/messages/3"
                    },
                    "status": "Failure",
                    "_embedded": {
                        "message": {
                            "direction": "Outgoing",
                            "timeStamp": "\/Date(1581608088182)\/",
                            "_links": {
                                "self": {"href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e/messaging/messages/3"},
                                "messaging": {"href": "/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/108/communication/conversations/39e/messaging"}
                            },
                            "rel": "message"
                        }
                    },
                    "reason": {
                        "code": "RemoteFailure",
                        "message": "Your request couldn\u0027t be completed.",
                        "debugInfo": {"errorReportId": "fb8aada02f7f47e6958b6c7df62e7bec"}
                    },
                    "type": "completed"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I forgetting? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem. It seems that there is an encoding error, so no message containing a accented character can be sent ("é", "è", "à", "ù", ...) without causing a failure.